# Java - Why is int in parenthesis in the following "maximum = (int)letter;"?

Tags: java, methods, int

[image: picture]

So I am wondering why int is in parenthesis and what role does it play/what does it do in the method minChar.

Comment: Because it is casting a char to an int

Comment: Please make your questions self-contained, not just with a link to another site, and write both the question and any code examples as text, not as images.

Comment: Please post the code instead of sharing the image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/1392/type-conversion/4544/numeric-primitive-casting#t=201610040443239038887

Answer (score 0):

As Scary Wombat mentioned in the comments, the "int" is in parenthesis because it is casting the char result into an int.

Any time you see something like this, it is there in order to make a variable of one type into a variable of another type.  This can be done to primitives as well as full-blown objects.  However, you must be careful when using casting as the variable you are trying to cast must be compatible with the type you are casting it to, otherwise, you will get exceptions.

For example if I had something like this, I will get errors:

```
String value = "value";
int intValue = (int)value;
```